# Regex to splitstring on date and keep it

Tags: regex, python-2.7, date, split

I have a string that I want to split on the date:

```
28/11/2016 Mushroom 05/12/2016 Carrot 12/12/2016 Broccoli 19/12/2016 Potato
```

which should end up as

```
 28/11/2016 Mushroom
 05/12/2016 Carrot
 12/12/2016 Broccoli
 19/12/2016 Potato
```

Obviously the date changes which makes it difficult. I've worked out the regex but I can't figure out how to keep the delimiter (the date) as well.

```
import re

s = "28/11/2016 Mushroom 05/12/2016 Carrot 12/12/2016 Broccoli 19/12/2016 Potato"

replaced = re.sub(r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s*", ",", s) # looses data
print replaced

g = re.match(r"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s*)(.*)", s)

if g:
  # replaced = s.replace(group(0), "\n" + g.group(0)) # fails
  # print replaced
```

Comment: use brackets (  )

Comment: Is there a whitespace before each subsequent date? Or can the dates be "glued"? I mean, can we split with the whitespace before the next date, you do you still need that whitespace in the results?

Comment: the string is in the form: date tab(s) or space(s) item space(s) item space(s) item space(s) etc...

Comment: Then my answer below is valid. Use the first approach then, since the spaces are there all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a splitting approach if there is always whitespace between the dates:

```
\s+(?=\d+/\d+/\d+\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/af1ylg/1)

**Details**:

- `\s+` - match 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=\d+/\d+/\d+\s)` - that are followed with 1+ digits, and `/` + one or more digits twice (the *date-like pattern*), and then a whitespace

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/T7P3WL) below:

```
import re
rx = r"\s+(?=\d+/\d+/\d+\s)"
s = "28/11/2016 Mushroom 05/12/2016 Carrot 12/12/2016 Broccoli 19/12/2016 Potato"
results = re.split(rx, s)
print(results)
```

Alternatively, a more complex regex can be used to actually match those dates:

```
\b\d+/\d+/\d+.*?(?=\s*\b\d+/\d+/\d+|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GoAkfd/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/K2EEcp):

```
import re
rx = r"\b\d+/\d+/\d+.*?(?=\b\d+/\d+/\d+|$)"
s = "28/11/2016 Mushroom 05/12/2016 Carrot 12/12/2016 Broccoli 19/12/2016 Potato"
results = re.findall(rx, s)
print(results)
```

Here,

- `\b\d+/\d+/\d+` - matches a word boundary and a date-like pattern
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first location that is followed with...
- `(?=\s*\b\d+/\d+/\d+|$)`  - 0+ whitespaces and a date-like pattern OR the end of string (`$`).