# Split string on hex colour

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Similar to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220172/regex-to-splitstring-on-date-and-keep-it)
I have a string with hex colours, no spaces and named colours.

```
#f503e1Pink59bf22greeny-green#"f7b925"orange#fffwhite
```

How can I split the string on each hex colour - split the string AND keep the delimiter?

```
#f503e1Pink
59bf22greeny-green
#"f7b925"orange
#fffwhite
```

The hex colours *may* be preceded by a # and *may* be surrounded by quotes and is *either* three or six characters long. The named colours can be any combination of characters of undetermined length.

```
(#?\"?[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}\"?)
```

Comment: I have no clue why you have such a string

Comment: I also think there may be some nasty edge cases where it is ambiguous as to how to make a split.

Comment: Think of it as a string splitting problem rather than a method of collecting matching colour names & matching hexcols. :)

Comment: This is impossible

Comment: It is not possible to provide a solution that will work in 100% cases as per *your specs*.

Comment: I also think its near impossible due to this kind of string `#f503e1Pink59bf22greeny-green`. How would I know that I am suppose to split after `Pink`

Comment: If you have control over the string generation, then consider making it a JSON string

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest, are you ready to get an approximate solution, just to cover your initial input and get the displayed expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

As other colleagues mentioned: *there's no 100% working solution for your current input that will cover all possible cases.*
To cover your particular input and output consider the following approach using `String.match()` function:

```js
var str = '#f503e1Pink59bf22greeny-green#"f7b925"orange#fffwhite',
    colors = str.match(/#?\"?[a-f0-9]{3,6}\"?[a-z-]+/gi);

console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have (and it's not pretty)

```
str = "#f503e1Pink59bf22greeny-green#\"f7b925\"orange#fffwhite";

reg = /(#?\"?[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}\"?)/gim

var res = str.match(reg);

str2 = str
var results = "";
h = [];
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
{
    var hex = res[i];
    results += hex + "\n";
    h.push(hex);
    str2 = str2.replace(hex, ", ");
}

sp = str2.split(", ");

// loose the first element ","
sp.shift();
alert(sp);


for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
{
    results += h[i] + " " + sp[i] + "\n";
}

alert(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i undersood well you nee dthe following:
i supposed a color (not hexa color) contain only letters . greeny-green is not a single color, is greeny and green. if this rule is eronate, please replace the 
[a-z]+ from the end with [a-z-]+ or include any other character needed.

```js
var string = '#f503e1Pink59bf22greeny-green#"f7b925"orange#fffwhite',
matches= string .match(/(#?\"?[a-f0-9]{6}\"?|#?\"?[a-f0-9]{3}\"?|[a-z]+)/gi);

console.log(matches);
```