# python regex - how do i split a string on a date pattern - only keep values after second occurrence of the date pattern

Tags: python, regex

i have a list of value , i need to separate them with the date pattern dd mmm yyyy

```
input_list = ['01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  559,929.32 **01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  0.00**',
 '01 Feb 2023 HKD  0.00  22,441,926.65 **01 Feb 2023 HKD  0.00  0.00**',
 '01 Feb 2023 USD  0.00  585,686.14 **01 Feb 2023 USD  0.00  0.00**']
```

hoping to get result:
df result :

```
currency     1stvalue   2ndvalue
CNY           0.00        0.00
HKD           0.00        0.00
USD           0.00        0.00
```

any direction or suggestion would help, thank you

i found similar method but still cant figure it out :
[Regex to splitstring on date and keep it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220172/regex-to-splitstring-on-date-and-keep-it)

similar example:

```
import re
rx = r"\b\d+/\d+/\d+.*?(?=\b\d+/\d+/\d+|$)"
s = "28/11/2016 Mushroom 05/12/2016 Carrot 12/12/2016 Broccoli 19/12/2016 Potato"
results = re.findall(rx, s)
print(results)
```

Comment: if the last two floats are what you are trying to capture then you can just split it by spaces and extract the last two

Comment: So you want to put those 3 values (currency, 1. value, 2. value) into a Pandas dataframe? If so, you don't need regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
import re

pattern = r"\d{2} [A-Z,a-z]{3} [0-9]{4} ([A-Z]{3})  (\d\.\d\d)"                                                                                             
string = "01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  559,929.32 **01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  0.00**"
responses = re.findall(pattern, string)

# printer
for i, response in enumerate(responses):
    if i == 0:
        print(response[0], end="")
    print(" ", response[1], end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can solve your problem

```py
import re

input_list = ['01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  559,929.32 **01 Feb 2023 CNY  0.00  0.00**',
 '01 Feb 2023 HKD  0.00  22,441,926.65 **01 Feb 2023 HKD  0.00  0.00**',
 '01 Feb 2023 USD  0.00  585,686.14 **01 Feb 2023 USD  0.00  0.00**']

currency_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w{3})\s+([0-9,.]+)')

output_dict = {}

for item in input_list:
    matches = re.findall(currency_pattern, item)
    matches.pop(0)
    matches.pop(1)
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            currency = match[0]
            value = match[1]
            if currency not in output_dict:
                output_dict[currency] = []
            output_dict[currency].append(value)

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output_dict, orient='index', columns=['value1', 'value2'])
new_df = new_df.rename_axis('currency').reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

Comment: hi Marchel , 

thank you for your reply , i m very new to regex usage , can you explain a little more one the pattern part

currency_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w{3})\s+([0-9,.]+)')



and i am actually trying to capture the two values after the 2nd occurrence of the date 

i.e. in this example:
['03 Feb 2023 HKD 0.00 24,232,494.96 03 Feb 2023 HKD 0.00 0.20',
'03 Feb 2023 USD 0.21 10,138,991.18 03 Feb 2023 USD 0.22 37,164,765.22']

i m trying to get result 
HKD ,        0.00,        0.20
USD ,          0.22,        37,164,765.22